# How to filter json array per each returned row?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with json field where array of objects is stored.
I would like to query this table and for each returned row return only subset of json array objects by filtering them using some condition.

For example for rows:

```
id = 1, jsonColumn = [{ field: 'abc' },{ field: 'def' },{ field: 'ghi' }]
id = 2, jsonColumn = [{ field: 'abc' },{ field: '123' },{ field: '456' }]
id = 3, jsonColumn = [{ field: 'abc' },{ field: '789' },{ field: 'XXX' }]
```

I would like to select ALL rows, and each row should contain in jsonColumn only elements `where field = 'abc'`. I just want to filter this column, and NOT return rows that contain specific element in array...

Comment: Who said that this is a problem? It's just a task, and it is easy to accomplish it with postgresql.

Comment: My jsonb format is looking like this 
{"key1":[
          {"new":"(888) 888 8888","old":"(999) 999 9999","field":"sec_phone"},
          {"new":"(888) 888 8888","old":"(999) 999 9999","field":"sec_phone"}
   ]
}

I want to search according to new field 

I got error in below mention  query 
Please help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `json_array_elements` to unnest JSON and `array_agg` to nest it back after filtering. Something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, array_to_json(array_agg(j))
FROM your_table t, json_array_elements(t.jsonColumn) j
WHERE j->>'field' = 'abc'
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: My jsonb format is looking like this 
{"key1":[
          {"new":"(888) 888 8888","old":"(999) 999 9999","field":"sec_phone"},
          {"new":"(888) 888 8888","old":"(999) 999 9999","field":"sec_phone"}
   ]
}

I want to search according to new field 

I got error in this query 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

### different ways to filter the records after extracting from the jsonb array elemnts

where clause for jsonb record

```
SELECT t.id,jsonRecord.VALUE
    FROM Table T
         cross JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(T.jsonbrecordarraycolumn) jsonRecord
    WHERE 
         --below filter with IN clause
         jsonRecord.VALUE ->> 'fieldName' IN ('filtertext')
        OR --below filter with like operator
         lower(jsonRecord.VALUE ->> 'fieldName') like ('%xyz%')
        OR -- below filter with number comparison
         jsonRecord.VALUE @? '$.fieldName ? (@ >= numberValueToFilter)'
        OR -- below filter for type cast and conditional filter
           case
            when (jsonRecord.VALUE ->> 'fieldName'::text) ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}' THEN
                date(jsonRecord.VALUE ->> 'fieldName') BETWEEN '2023-08-24' and '2024-08-28'
            ELSE true
            End
```