# How do I search within an JSON array of hashes by hash values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

I am using Postgres' JSON data type to store some information.

For example I have model `User` with a field `locations` that holds a json document(array of objects containing pairs of keys and values) in the following format:

```
[{"name": "Location 1", kind: "house"},
 {"name": "Location 2", kind: "house"},
 {"name": "Location 3", kind: "office"},
 ...
 {"name": "Location X", kind: "house"}
]
```

I want to query with `.where` on the JSON data type.

I want to query for users that have at least one location with `kind = office`.

Thanks!

Comment: It might help you: http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 18):

> I want to query for users that have locations with kind `office`

```
# if locations is jsonb type
User.where('locations @> ?', { kind: 'office' }.to_json)
# if locations is json type
User.where("locations->>'kind' = 'office'")
# if locations is array of hashes
User.where('locations @> ?', [{ kind: 'office' }].to_json)
```

Comment: `@>` is `jsonb` operators. Unfortunately, I have `json`.

Comment: I've tried, but it's not working.  It alway returns an empty result.

Comment: @mamantoha how come? It is the way you query json pg column. What's the issue with that?

Comment: I think the problem is _array_ of _hashes_.

Comment: @mamantoha please let me know, whether `User.where("'office' = ANY (SELECT unnest(\"#{locations}\") -> 'kind')")` worked for you when you have it tested

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `locations'

Comment: @mamantoha it should have been just `locations`, not a variable. edited

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function unnest(json) does not exist`

and

`HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help. I migrate my data from json to jsonb. And this works for me `User.where('locations @> ?', [{ kind: 'office' }].to_json)`

Answer (score 6):

I have used a mix of above answers. This is my working code:

```
User.where("locations::jsonb @> ?", [{kind: 'office'}].to_json)
```

As a note, `locations` is a `JSON` column of `User` table (not `JSONB` datatype)

Answer (score 4):

## Filters based on the values of objects inside array JSONB

If you want to **make filters based on the values of the objects (jsonb) inside the arrays in Rails with postgres** you can use something like example below.

*Assuming you have a **Product** model:*

```
Product.select("*").from(
  Product.select("*, jsonb_array_elements(registers) as register")
).where("(register ->> 'price')::numeric >= 1.50")
```

In above example we select all products with price greater than or equal 1.50.

For this we use:

- [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) from postgres;
- an [auxiliary column and alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24806907/2632214);
- and [methods from ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212461/2632214) from Rails.

I applied ident in sub-query just for best readability.

After you can put this in a scope or use other best practice.

Answer (score 3):

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

```
User.where("name::jsonb -> 'location' ->> 'kind' = ?", 'office')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give my two cents:

I have a model with a JSON with a key and an array inside, so it looks like this:

```
ModelObj: attribute: { key: [val0, val1, val2, val3] }
```

I needed to find all objects with, for example, attributes where the key has val3 in the array.
I changed my attribute type to jsonb and this was how I find it:

```
Model.where('attribute @> ?', {key: ['val3']}.to_json)
```

Maybe it's useful to someone out there.