# How to use a where query to check a value inside a JSON field in rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named `Notification` with a JSON field along with other fields.

I am listing all notifications using `@notification`

```
@notifications = current_user.notifications
```

`@notifications` carry an array of notifications of that user.

I'm now implementing a search feature in notification. We have

```
params[:search] = abc@gmail.com
```

In our method we have a params of searched email id

```
notification_user_id = User.find_by(email: params[:search]).id
```

Here we are finding the corresponding user with the email id and taking its id to `notification_user_id` which is used to find the notifications

Now I want to refactor the `@notifications` with a 'where query' like

```
@notifications = current_user.notifications.where(user_id: notification_user_id)
```

For reference, fields in notification table:

```
current_user.notification.last
```

Here taking last notification of `current_user` for reference purpose

```
#<Notification:0x00007f3a9488b4b0                                                                      
 id: 6,   
 recipient_type: "User",   
 recipient_id: 1,           
 type: "TicketNotification",       
 params:                 
  {:ticket=>           
    #<Ticket:0x00007f3a94898bb0    
     id: 11,
     user_id: 2, 
     complaint: "complaint 1",
     complaint_type: "suggestion",
     created_at: Mon, 17 Oct 2022 12:30:20.755854000 UTC +00:00,
     updated_at: Mon, 17 Oct 2022 12:30:20.755854000 UTC +00:00,
     status: "pending",
     deleted_at: nil>}
```

*Requirement*:

I need a where query which return all notifications where `user_id: notification_user_id`. Remember that field `params` is a JSON field, inside that JSON field we have user id.

So how to get all data by checking a field inside a JSON field?

Comment: If `params` is a JSON datatype column what's the JSON object type that the key `ticket` holds?

Comment: can you please check this once. `Notification.where("params -> 'ticket' ->> 'user_id' = #{notification_user_id} ")`

Comment: We have another table Ticket. Here params[:ticket] is an object from the table Ticket

Comment: @AmolMohite it is returning Object doesn't support #inspect error

Comment: Which database are you using? What is the column type? Including the schema for the table from `schema.rb` would help.

Comment: @muistooshort database used here is PostgreSQL and column type is jsonb

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use LIKE query

```
@notifications = current_user.notifications.where("params LIKE ?", "%user\_id: #{notification_user_id}%")
```

Comment: Raising Object doesn't support #inspect error any other methods

Comment: Have a look at this issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/39895445